# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in URLpattern

Tags: python, django, syntax

hi am getting a syntax error

url:

```
url(r'^reset-password/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/reset_password.html', 'post_reset_redirect': 'accounts:password_reset_done'), name='reset_password'),
```

What is the problem?

thanks

Comment: You used a `colon` in `'post_reset_redirect': 'accounts:password_reset_done'`, instead of `post_reset_redirect='accounts:password_reset_done'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you mix dictionary syntax with parameter syntax:

```
url(
    r'^reset-password/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/reset_password.html',
        'post_reset_redirect': 'accounts:password_reset_done'
    ),
    name='reset_password'
)
```

This syntax with a colon, is used for dictionaries. For parameters, it is `identifier=expression`, so:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

url(
    r'^reset-password/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/reset_password.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')
    ),
    name='reset_password'
)
```

The `post_reset_redirect` has been removed as parameter, but the `success_url` performs the same functionality: it is the URL to which a redirect is done, after the POST request has been handled successfully.

The wrong syntax probably originates from the fact that when you used a *function-based view*, you passed parameters through the `kwargs` paramter, which accepted a dictionary.

The class-based view however, obtains these parameter through the `.as_view(..)` call. Furthermore class-based views typically aim to generalize the process, and there the `success_url`, is used for `FormView`s.

Comment: thanks im getting this error now:
    TypeError: PasswordResetView() received an invalid keyword 'post_reset_redirect'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.

Comment: when I do that I get a syntax error with my urlpattern closing bracket ]...i tried )) at end of urlpattern but then i get 'NameError: name 'reverse_lazy' is not defined

Comment: @JosephS: no, yyou need to import it: `from django.urls import reverse_lazy`.

Comment: The brackets are - afaik - correct (note that we colose both of them, one at the line in boldface, and one at the next line).